# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS - WPA3-Enterprise (PEAP) Support

Tags: wireless, 22.04, iwlwifi, wpa-supplicant, wpa3

I've been searching the web for hours and can't seem to find an answer anywhere. Does or will Ubuntu 22.04 LTS support WPA3-Enterprise?

Currently, it does not seem to allow me to select WPA3-Enterprise, only WPA/WPA2-Enterprise or WPA3-Personal.

Thanks!